# AVPlayer doesn't load video after some specific count

Tags: swift, uitableview, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller, avplayerlayer

I am using AVPlayer to load video from local storage inside the table view cell to show video multiple time.

It works fine for 16 times but as I load the cell 17 times it doesn't get loaded and shows error

[image]

I tried to use different video size but it still doesn't get fixed!

Here Code

```
var player : AVPlayer? = nil
var playerLayer : AVPlayerLayer? = nil
var asset : AVAsset? = nil
var playerItem: AVPlayerItem? = nil

            var videoURLWithPath = str

            let videoURL = NSURL(string: videoURLWithPath)

            self.asset = AVAsset(url: videoURL! as URL)

            self.playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: self.asset!)

            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.playerDidFinishPlaying(sender:)), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: self.playerItem)

            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.playerDidNotLoaded(sender:)), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemFailedToPlayToEndTime, object: self.playerItem)

            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.playerDidNotLoaded(sender:)), name: Notification.Name.AVPlayerItemNewErrorLogEntry, object: self.playerItem)
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.playerDidNotLoaded(sender:)), name: Notification.Name.AVPlayerItemPlaybackStalled, object: self.playerItem)

            self.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: self.playerItem)

            // When you need to update the UI, switch back out to the main thread
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                // Main thread
                // Do your UI updates here

                let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()

                playerViewController.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
                playerViewController.player = self.player
                //playerViewController.showsPlaybackControls = false
                view.addChildViewController(playerViewController)
                view.didMove(toParentViewController: playerViewController)
                playerViewController.view.frame.size.width = self.videoView.frame.width
                playerViewController.view.frame.size.height = self.videoView.frame.height
                self.videoView.addSubview(playerViewController.view)

                if self.player?.rate == nil{

                    view.showAlert(withMessage: "Vidoe didn't found")

                    self.continueBtn.isHidden = false

                }

                self.player!.pause()

            }
```

Comment: Some code would be helpful.

Comment: A new `AVPlayerViewController` is created every time the cell is configured?

Comment: Thanks, @Fabian your comment made to make a global variable and it gets fixed Thank You